# Как преобразовать объект базового класса в объект производного класса?

Tags: c#

Использовать операторы explicit и implicit для этого нельзя по документации. Можно ли это красиво реализовать? Или просто метод/конструктор делать?

Кратко о ситуации: в первой dll описан базовый класс (Base) и всяческие методы, возвращающие объект базового класса (public Base Foo()). Вторая dll использует первую dll, в ней описан класс, наследуемый на базовом (Child: Base)  и методы, принимающие потомка (public void Bar(Child c)). В итоге хотим сделать так Bar(Foo()).

Comment: Эээ, возможно, вам нужен просто каст? Ваш объект реально производного типа, или базового? Покажите код.

Comment: @VladD , объекты реально разного типа, попыталась объяснить это в тексте вопроса.

Comment: `Bar(Foo())` - так делать не следует, да и компилятор не даст. Варианты: `Bar((Child)Foo())` - исключение в случае, когда результат `Foo` не `Child`; `Bar(Foo() as Child)` - нужна проверка на `null` внутри `Bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, раз это реально разные типы, возникает вопрос, можно ли из экземпляра базового типа построить экземпляр производного.

Если невозможно, то задача, понятно, не имеет решения.

Если возможно, то проще всего, наверное, делать это при помощи extension-метода:

```
// первая DLL
class Point2D
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

class First
{
    public static Point2D Foo() => new Point2D() { X = 1, Y = 2 };
}
```

```
// вторая DLL
class Point3D : Point2D
{
    public double Z { get; set; }
}

static class PointExtensions
{
    public static Point3D LiftTo3D(this Point2D self) =>
        new Point3D() { X = self.X, Y = self.Y, Z = 0 };
}

class Program
{
    public static void Bar(Point3D p) { /* ... */ }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Bar(First.Foo().LiftTo3D());
    }
}
```

---

Обратите внимание, что при этом вы будете работать не с тем объектом, который возвращён из первой DLL, а с совершенно посторонним. Так что изменения в этом постороннем объекте не будут отражаться на первоначальном объекте. Если вас это не устраивает, то производному классу (в примере `Point3D`) придётся агрегировать базовый (`Point2D`). (Да, это расходно и неудобно, но если такое понадобилось, нужно ли вам наследование реально?)

Comment: Насчет ненужности наследования в данном случае действительно сомневаюсь.

Comment: @Julidae: Ну это уж вы смотрите по вашей задаче. Моё дело — спросить и предупредить :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте UpCast и DownCast.

Сначала нужно создать экземпляр производного класса. Затем привести его к базовому классу - и если есть необходимость его обратно можно привести к производному классу. Зачем это используется можно прочитать [на форуме](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1404744.html). Просто так с экземпляра базового типа к производному нельзя привестись(насколько мне известно)

Comment: В том-то и проблема, что экземпляр базового класса приходи ко мне из подключенной dll, а производный я создаю.

Comment: а что мешает создать экземпляр класса который наследует базовый? не могу понять проблемы. включи библиотеку в сборку и подключи неймспейс с помощью using

Comment: @Volodymyr: Проблема, очевидно, в том, что объект создаётся в неподконтрольной сборке, которая не знает о порождённом объекте.